# How do I add mods to Minecraft PS4 without a computer?

Tags: ps4, minecraft-legacy-console, minecraft-mods

Can I add mods to Minecraft on the PS4 without a computer?  How would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

if you have Minecraft on a mobile device you can get the mod you want on the mobile device and on invite your ps4 profile to it and that should work if it doesn't check this video.

Answer (score -3):

Unless you jailbreak the ps4 and ask someone to make a mod suitable for minecraft on ps4 than no. Sorry because for one thing there is no mod capable on a PS4 and 2 you need to jailbreak a PS4 first. Sorry, no mods for ps4 unless you know how to program in java and know how to jailbreak a PS4.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why the three iterations of the same information?

Comment: **DO NOT DO THIS.** Jailbreaking a PlayStation is **illegal** and Sony will be able to tell and **ban you.**

Comment: @Penguin Yes but thousands of people do it anyway. It's not illegal lmao

Comment: @RayWu it seems that installing unauthorized software is illegal from my findings, so I'd say yes this is illegal. However I can't find info that says that this is legal, if you just look it up plenty of things say that installing that is illegal. Maybe the act itself isn't but it basically is bc the next step (and the reason you do it) does seem to be illegal

Comment: @Penguin Many people jailbreak their devices for legitimate reasons, such as

Comment: @RayWu such as... anyway we're not talking about devices in general were talking about PlayStations

Comment: @Penguin this conversation should in chat., and also I would jailbreak PS4 if I had one for a custom ROM and themes, running nonstandard software such as emulators and modding as in the question " installing unauthorized software is illegal from my finding" source?

Comment: @RayWu idk its not popping up idk how to make one

Comment: @RayWu could you invite me to one

Comment: @Penguin https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124958/penguin-doesnt-like-jailbreaking